# XBAP Support in IE Edge

Tags: wpf, internet-explorer, windows-10, xbap, microsoft-edge

I was building an WPF Browser application as such it requires many client specific functionality.

During debugging when i tried to run this application in IE Edge it starts behaving in buggy way i.e. it keeps downloading XBAP file in recursion again & again but when I saw the folder it does not contain any XBAP file.

My application works perfectly fine in IE11, I am not sure if Microsoft have removed the support of XBAP from IE Edge ????

I am wishing to have it cross browser application, any guidance / help would be much appreciated.

Thanks & Regards,
Srujal Kachhela

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Edge does **not** support XBAP, and never will.

(I work on Edge)

Comment: then how am i suppose to create an web application supported by most of all versions of windows i.e. at least till XP :O, as such it will be mess then are there any other workaround for the same or any Idea ??

Comment: by using standard web technologies, like most websites.

Comment: You can't do with standard web technologies what you can do with an xbap app, as an example access the serial ports, so it's not really an option

Comment: @Patrick: can you confirm that XBAP will never be supported by Microsoft Edge or are we just waiting for a Windows Upgrade to fix this?

Comment: it will never be supported.

Comment: Can you please explain why?

Comment: Internet Explorer will die on 15th June 2022. Where can I run XBAP files?

Comment: The bits will still exist. You can still run IE. It just will not get any kind of update, security or otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

Chronium based Edge supports XBAP

you need

msedge.admx in C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions

msedge.adml in C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\en-US

run gpedit.msc and navigate to "Microsoft Edge"

"Configure Internet Explorer integration" --> Activate --> Option: "Internet Explorer mode"
"Configure the Enterprise Mode Site List" --> Activate --> Option: point to a xml file like "file:///C:/EdgeSites.xml"

EdgeSites.xml

```
<site-list version="3">
    <created-by>
        <tool>EMIESiteListManager</tool>
        <version>10.0.14357.1004</version>
        <date-created>01/08/2020 14:09:07</date-created>
    </created-by>
    <site url="myurl.com/site1">
        <open-in>IE11</open-in>
    </site>
</site-list>
```

Comment: What do you need to do if you don't have those files in PolicyDefinitions?

Comment: I followed your instructions, but it still performs a download of the .xbap file instead of executing it. Any suggestions?

Comment: @SimonTribus you need to add the url to trusted sites

Comment: @Coder14 you can download the templates from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/configure-microsoft-edge

Answer (score 3):

you can enable IE mode on Microsoft Edge (Chromium based)

1. Go to Edge browser settings and click on Default browser
2. Under the “Internet Explorer compatibility” section, turn on the “Allow sites to be reloaded in Internet Explorer mode” toggle switch
3. Click the Restart button.
4. Add your site to Internet Explorer mode pages

[image]

5. add your site to trusted sites : Control panel->Internet options -> Security tab -> select "Trusted site" and click on "Sites"