WPF Browser App not running on Visual studio 2022
i have XBAP project run correctly with Visual Studio 2013 running on windows 11..
but i cannot run it with visual studio 2022 (wpf browser apps still exists in visual studio 2022, we can add new projects)
it's running on edge browser (chromuiom based) after update the "Internet Explorer mode" settings https://stackoverflow.com/a/70820754/2713855
error details: File, WpfBrowserApp3.exe, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows : 10.0.22631.0 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime : 4.0.30319.42000
System.Deployment.dll : 4.8.9176.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_B
clr.dll : 4.8.9181.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_C
dfdll.dll : 4.8.9176.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_B
dfshim.dll : 10.0.22621.30000 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

SOURCES
Deployment url : file:///C:/Users/user/source/repos/WpfBrowserApp3/WpfBrowserApp3/bin/Debug/WpfBrowserApp3.xbap
Application url : file:///C:/Users/user/source/repos/WpfBrowserApp3/WpfBrowserApp3/bin/Debug/WpfBrowserApp3.exe.manifest

IDENTITIES
Deployment Identity : WpfBrowserApp3.xbap, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ec569a7ebac193ca, processorArchitecture=msil
Application Identity : WpfBrowserApp3.exe, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ec569a7ebac193ca, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
* Online only application.
* Browser-hosted application.

ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* An exception occurred while downloading the application. Following failure messages were detected:
+ File, WpfBrowserApp3.exe, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
No phase information is available.

ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [03/02/2024 19:58:00] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (HashValidation)
- File, WpfBrowserApp3.exe, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest.
- Source: System.Deployment
- Stack trace:
at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyFileHash(String filePath, Hash hash)
at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyFileHash(String filePath, HashCollection hashCollection)
at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.FileComponent.Verify()
at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyComponents()
at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.SynchronizeCore(Boolean blocking)
at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.SynchronizeAsyncWorker()

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
No transaction information is available.


With visual studio 2022 after starting a project its calling by defualt PresentationHost.exe for 32bit version .. need to change it to use 64bit version
In the project property settings, under the Start Action section, select Start external program and choose “C:\Windows\SysWOW64\PresentationHost.exe”. Then the app can debug normally on my Win11.
